# Extract email adresses from text using RegEx c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have code in console app

```
reg = new Regex(@"/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i");
  string text = "wjeqklejqwek myEmail@hotmail.com a;lekqlwe anothermail@mail.ru";
  parseTextByTagName("", text);
  MatchCollection coll =   reg.Matches(text);
}
```

when I debug it it shows that the coll is empty could you tell whats problem I am solving it about an hour

Comment: You do know that your regular expression doesn't come near to covering all valid email addresses?

Comment: This, for example, is a valid email address - `"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com` - and so is this - `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{}|~@example.org`

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
string strRegex = @"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"wjeqklejqwek myEmail@hotmail.com a;lekqlwe anothermail@mail.ru";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: it wokred!!!! what waas the problem? thanks man

Comment: Thank you for your code it's work 100%

Comment: this regex does not work for dot in the email address eg.   a.b@c.com won't work.  to fix use this instead @"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?"

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression worked for me if I take out `/` & `/i`.

`[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?`

alternatively, you can also use this...

`/^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$/`